# what happens when compare string to int in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a hive table A which has a uuid column and its type is string

I want to count the number of uuids which uuid is not 0 and I wrote the sql below

```
select
    count(distinct union_id)
from
   A
where dt = 20180610 and (union_id <> 0)
```

the result is about 2 million.

As I know the uuid in my table is about 20 million so I start to check what's wrong.

Finally I found out that my `uuid` column  is `string` , not `int`. I guess maybe there is some cast that convert the `uuid` to `0`. then I fixed my program as follows:

```
select
   count(distinct union_id)
from
   A
where dt = 20180610 and (union_id <> '0')
```

and it gives a number about 20 million as I expected.

my uuid  has two formats, one is long string that has many letters， the other is just a number string .  I guess the second format will be casted to 0 but I'm not sure.

Can someone explain this?

Thanks!!

here is some uuid examples:

```
BE04A886FAE1F6BC00015A3A4C259466106F1EA587D74140E762E093FA6D58BB
9AF57081FE81FEA1EF88B293F82029418F6FBA19D8EB0F8BCCAEC3F033681F94
-8255088809384245133
976054595992186950
```

Answer (score 0):

This difference is coming from your empty values. Hive will perform implicit conversion from  string to double (and int to double) trying to compare the values (you can see implicit conversion table [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-AllowedImplicitConversions)), however for empty values (or non numeric values) the result of the comparison will be null, making your where condition false

```
select "0" <> 0; -- false
select "hlagos" <> 0; -- NULL
select "" <> 0; -- NULL
```

This does not happen when you compare the correct data types

```
select "" <> "0"; -- true
```